# How do I add TableRows dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio, tablerow

I'm trying to create a new Table row and add it into an existing TableLayout. I have scoured the Internet and it seems like I've tried everything but I cant get the new row to show. If I add a TableRow with an id in the layout and add my custom ImageView to that without adding the new TableRow to the layout the ImageView shows but I need to add a new row dynamically. In my Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_default_view, 
  container, false);

  final ViewGroup tableLayout = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById
     (R.id.table_bracket);

  TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
          TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
  );

  TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
  tableRow.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

  SeparatorImageView separator = new SeparatorImageView(getActivity());
  separator.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

  tableRow.addView(separator);
  tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
  return rootView;
}
```

here's the layout I'm trying to add to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.mbusby.bracketsandbox.DefaultViewFragment">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/table_bracket"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:stretchColumns="*">

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line after tableLayout.addView(tableRow); line

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
```

to refresh tableview newly added row will be visible

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm using a fragment so i wrote the same thing but with getActivity() before it

Comment: I added this directly after tableLayout.getView(tableRow):      getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();

Comment: why are you using viewgroup you cast your view in tableLayout too

Comment: I read it's a good practice in case it gets changed I wont have to refactor. I don't think it's an issue as I have tried casting directly to TableLayout as well and it still doesn't work